# Remove Line Breaks HTML

Tags: html

Currently, all the `<p>` elements on my page are being displayed like this:

> First
>
> Second
>
> And so on...

I want there to be no margins between each `p` element.

Comment: What's your CSS for these elements?

Comment: do you mean that you don't want vertical whitespace between them?

Comment: There is no CSS...yet...

Comment: do you want to replace your `<p>` with `<br>` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can change it by modifying CSS:

```
​p {
  margin: 0px;
}​
```

Comment: @Kolink I miclicked save button before I typed up the code, so some might have just seen the first sentence before I finished editing it.